# How to make a std::shared_ptr type argument convert to Base Class automatically?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

```cpp
#include <utility>

#include "iostream"

template<class Vty>
class Base {
public:
    Base(Vty value) : _baseValue(std::move(value)) {}

    virtual auto print() -> void {
        std::cout << "This class is Base, " << _baseValue << std::endl;
    }

protected:
    Vty _baseValue;
};

template<class Vty>
class Derived : public Base<Vty> {
public:
    Derived(Vty value) : Base<Vty>(value) {}

    auto print() -> void override {
        std::cout << "This class is Derived," << this->_baseValue << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class Vty>
auto print(const std::shared_ptr<Base<Vty>> &instance) -> void {
    instance->print();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto base = std::make_shared<Base<std::string>>("this is value");
    print(base);    //this line is normal.
    auto derived = std::make_shared<Derived<std::string>>("this is value");
    print(derived); //this line will report an error.
}
```

This code will report an error:

```
No matching function for call to 'print' candidate template ignored: could not match 'Base' against 'Derived'
```

I tried to make `print` like this feel:

```cpp
template<template<class>class Cty, class Vty, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<Cty<Vty>, Base<Vty>>>* = nullptr>
auto print(const std::shared_ptr<Cty<Vty>> &instance) -> void {
    instance->print();
}
```

Change `print` like this then it will be worked, but what should I do if I want to use `print` function like before or it's impossible? Like add some operators?

Comment: Again using trailing return type when you already know the return type, doesn't make sense. Change `auto print() -> void override` to `void print() override`

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: If you want to call the derived function, then why not just `void print(const std::shared_ptr<auto> &instance) -> void {
    instance->print();
}`. Unless you really need a `print_base()`

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work: `print(std::static_pointer_cast<Base<std::string>>(derived));`

Comment: As @kiner_shah said, if you really need to call the base function, put `std::static_pointer_cast` inside `print()`

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You know how to rewrite `print` so that it works. Are you asking how to call the old version of `print`? Try `print<std::string>(derived)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template deduction happens before parameters are converted. In your case there is no deduction for `Vty`, because `Derived<std::string>` isn't `Base<std::string>`.

You can explicitly pass the type to the template, and then it doesn't have to deduce it, and so the implicit pointer conversion can occur

```
print<std::string>(derived);
```

Alternately, you can explicitly convert, and allow template deduction to occur.

```
print(std::static_pointer_cast<Base<std::string>>(derived));
```